# Helper method that returns a thing, or causes a return in the calling scope / context

Tags: java, design-patterns, java-8, exception, option-type

I can't figure out how to factor out this code.

```
  private CompletionStage<Response<String>> foo(RequestContext rc) {

    final Optional<String> campaignIdOpt = rc.request().parameter("campaignId").filter(s -> !s.isEmpty());
    final Optional<String> creativeIdOpt = rc.request().parameter("creativeId").filter(s -> !s.isEmpty());

    Optional<Uuid> campaignIdOptOfUuid = Optional.empty();
    if (campaignIdOpt.isPresent()) {
      try {
        campaignIdOptOfUuid = Optional.of(UuidUtils.fromString(campaignIdOpt.get()));
      } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        LOG.error(String.format("Invalid campaignId: %s", campaignIdOpt.get()), e);
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(
            Response.forStatus(Status.BAD_REQUEST.withReasonPhrase("Invalid campaignId provided.")));
      }
    }

    Optional<Uuid> creativeIdOptOfUuid = Optional.empty();
    if (creativeIdOpt.isPresent()) {
      try {
        creativeIdOptOfUuid = Optional.of(UuidUtils.fromString(creativeIdOpt.get()));
      } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        LOG.error(String.format("Invalid creativeId: %s", creativeIdOpt.get()), e);
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(
            Response.forStatus(Status.BAD_REQUEST.withReasonPhrase("Invalid creativeId provided.")));
      }
    }

    // Simplified, do something with Uuids.
    return bar(campaignIdOptOfUuid, creativeIdOptOfUuid);
  }
```

Basically, we very frequently need to parse Google protobuf `Uuid`s from a query string to pass on to another service that will find (or not find). We need to pass along an empty optional if a parameter was not set or an empty string, as both cases mean, "Don't filter by this parameter."  Finally, if the string doesn't parse at all, then we want to immediately return an error 400 (Bad Request), rather than pass along a non-sense param to the service.

So, codewise, I want a utility method that

1. takes an `Optional<String>`, and
2. returns an `Optional<Uuid>` if present, `Optional.empty()` otherwise, and
3. if an exception is thrown, `return` an error from the *original* context.

But obviously, I can't "double-return." What pattern do I use to achieve this though? I tried to create an encapsulator for both an `Optional<Uuid>` and a `CompletionStage<Response<String>>` but it was awkward. Is there some idiomatic way of doing this?

Comment: this would belong to code review, it seems

Comment: @DwB (while your answer is deleted) - Sorry, there was a mistake in my sample. The `.isPresent()` should have been on the original optionals, not the one set right above. Good catch. While simplifying my example I made a bad copy-paste.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a loop. A loop allows you to handle all elements equally, thus removing the code duplication, while still allowing to return immediately:

```
private CompletionStage<Response<String>> foo(RequestContext rc) {
    String[] parameters = {"campaignId", "creativeId" };
    List<Optional<Uuid>> uuids = new ArrayList<>(parameters.length);
    for(String param: parameters) {
        Optional<String> o1 = rc.request().parameter(param).filter(s -> !s.isEmpty());
        Optional<Uuid> o2;
        try {
            o2 = o1.map(UuidUtils::fromString);
        } catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
            LOG.error(String.format("Invalid %s: %s", param, o1.get()), e);
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(
                Response.forStatus(Status.BAD_REQUEST
                    .withReasonPhrase("Invalid "+param+ " provided.")));
        }
        uuids.add(o2);
    }
    // Simplified, do something with Uuids.
    return bar(uuids.get(0), uuids.get(1));
}
```

Otherwise, you would need to create a method returning an object holding two alternative results (like `Either`); the JDK does not provide such a type yet. A method could simply throw on an erroneous condition but that would bring you back to square one when the common code is mostly the exception handling.

Note that calling `Optional.map` on an empty optional will already return an empty optional, without evaluating the provided function, so you don’t need to check via `ifPresent`, etc.